# Maximum size of MongoDB insert

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I'm inserting a document in Mongo from PHP.

I get the following error

```
Uncaught exception 'MongoException' with message 'insert too large: 16458711, max: 16000000'
```

But the Mongo documentation says the limit is [16MB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/), and the document is 15.7MB.

Is the documentation incorrect, or is this a PHP-specific driver issue, or what?

Comment: How are you calculating the size of the document to be 15.7MB? The documentation isn't wrong. It's 16MB. The error suggests your document, when converted to BSON is too large, by about 450K.

Comment: How do you calculate 15.7? The exception is thrown once the document has been BSON encoded. Depending on how exactly you are attempting to insert it, there may be few bytes protocol overhead, although not 3kb worth